# Windows Server 2008 R2 Cluster with just two nodes

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql, failover

May be this question was already made, but I dont find an exact answer to my dilema.

I have a consulting IT job, my client have only 2 servers (16GB RAM, 2 Xeon 5160 and 500GB HDD) and him want to do a SQL Server R2 failover cluster, the Windows Server and sql server licences are not a problem, but I must do that with only 2 servers. There is no aditional servers besides one pfSense firewall and 2 MySQL servers, thats the reason I must do that with just 2 servers.

Additionally the two servers will have an ASP.NET application for internal use but must be failover two, I guest this can be done as a web farm too.

Can I do this setup? is there any tutorial?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: You don't appear to have a specific problem, other than wanting someone to tell you how to do your job. Yes, you can have a failover cluster with only two servers (you need shared storage). Google will give you plenty of info.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. You need external storage to build a cluster. Having two stand-alone servers is not enought.